# Nothing showing in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have this class for a [JFrame][1], but nothing is showing up.  However, if I remove the setLayout the temp panel shows up, but if I add other components they do not show up.I've added the Panel now

```
public class GenerateQuestions extends JFrame {
    List<ButtonGroup> btngp;

    GenerateQuestions() {
    setSize(400, 400);
    btngp = new LinkedList<ButtonGroup>();

    String[] contents =
    {
        "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"
    };
    SpringLayout z = new SpringLayout();
    setLayout(z); 
    JPanel temp = new JPanel(); 
    SpringLayout sl = new SpringLayout();
    temp.setLayout(sl);
    JLabel x = new JLabel("This is a test question generator for online assesment ");
    temp.add(x);
    sl.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, x, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, temp);
    sl.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, x, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, temp); 

    ButtonGroup btn = new ButtonGroup();
    int counterNorth = 15;
    int counterWest = 15;
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
        JRadioButton t = new JRadioButton(contents[i]);
        btn.add(t);
        temp.add(t);
        sl.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, t, counterNorth, SpringLayout.NORTH, x);
        sl.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, t, counterWest, SpringLayout.WEST, temp);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
        counterWest += 75;
        } else {
        counterWest -= 75;
        counterNorth += 25;
        }
    }
    btngp.add(btn);
    z.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, temp, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
    z.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, temp, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
    setVisible(true);
    getContentPane().add(temp);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GenerateQuestions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add all your components to `temp` panel, but you never add that panel to your `JFrame`. Add this line `setContentPane(temp);` before `setVisible(true);` and all will be work.

EDIT: If you want to add more that one panel to your `JFrame` use `LayoutManager` for example `GridLayout` :

```
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    getContentPane().add(temp);
    getContentPane().add(new JLabel("test"));
```

or you can use  `BorderLayout` like this `getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());` it also helps you.

By default your `getContentPane()` panel has `FlowLayout` which can't display components with preferedSize(0,0) . If you want to use it you must to specify size of your components, for example : `temp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));`

[LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

[GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

[BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)

Comment: yes i've done it but nothing happens,Any more suggestion please

Answer (score 1):

You should set the temp panel to be the content pane of the JFrame.

Add

```
setContentPane( temp );
```

before showing the frame with `setVisible( true );`.

Comment: I've missed that part.Sorry.I had already added it but nothing happens.Also i cannot do setContentPane( temp ) because i will have many more panels

Comment: Yeah, I was to slow in typing, it seems ;)

Comment: It seems, that you plan something more complex. You can use the [TableLayout](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html) Layout Manager.